# Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm for 3D data

Tags: matlab, data-fitting

I have a point cloud in 3D whose coordinates are stored in a 3D vector, and I would like to fit a nonlinear function to the point cloud.

Do you know if the [`lsqcurvefit`](https://mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqcurvefit.html) algorithm implemented in MATLAB works for 3D data as well?

Do you have any example data that uses `'levenberg-marquardt'` for 3D data using MATLAB?

```matlab
options = optimoptions('lsqcurvefit','Algorithm','levenberg-marquardt');
```

Comment: From the documentation of lsqcurvefit: "given input data xdata, and the observed output ydata, where xdata and ydata are matrices or vectors". So yes, they can be N-D. Just try it, the call to lsqcurvefit should be independent of how many dimensions the data has.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can still use `lsqcurvefit` in 3D, but if you want to keep your code as simple as possible (see edit) I suggest the [`lsqnonlin`](https://it.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqnonlin.html) function for multivariate nonlinear data fitting. The linked documentation page shows several examples, one of which uses the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm in 2D. In 3D or higher, the usage is similar.

For instance, suppose you have a cloud of points in 3D whose coordinates are stored in the arrays `x`, `y` and `z`. Suppose you are looking for a fitting surface (no longer a curve because you are in 3D) of the form `z = exp(r1*x + r2*y)`, where `r1` and `r2` are coefficients to be found. You start by defining the following inline function

```
fun = @(r) exp(r(1)*x + r(2)*y) - z;
```

where `r` is an unknown 1x2 array whose entries will be your unknown coefficients (`r1` and `r2`). We are ready to solve the problem:

```
r0 = [1,1]; % Initial guess for r
options = optimoptions(@lsqnonlin, 'Algorithm', 'levenberg-marquardt');
lsqnonlin(fun, r0, [], [], options)
```

You will get the output on the command window.

Tested on MATLAB 2018a.

Hope that helps.

### EDIT: `lsqcurvefit` vs `lsqnonlin`

`lsqcurvefit` is basically a [special case](https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/158328-difference-between-pem-lsqnonlin-and-lsqcurvefit) of `lsqnonlin`. The discussion on whichever is better in terms of speed and accuracy is wide and is beyond the scope of this post. There are two reasons why I have suggested `lsqnonlin`:

- You are free to take `x`, `y`, `z` as matrices instead of column vectors, just make sure that the dimensions match. In fact, if you use `lsqcurvefit`, your `fun` must have an additional argument `xdata` defined as `[x, y]` where `x` and `y` are taken in column form.
- You are free to choose your fitting function `fun` to be implicit, that is of the form `f(x,y,z)=0`.

Comment: Could the OP also use lsqcurvefit?

Comment: @Trilarion yes, thanks for pointing that out. I have edited my answer accordingly.